# How to read this barcode?

Tags: ocr, barcode

How to find out which type of barcode is this in my sample ? I looked on wikipedia and there are quite many types of barcodes, most common should be Code 39 and Code 128.

Is there any lib for barcode OCR (python, java, C#, delphi) ? 
[image]

On this barcode should be encoded time and date of expiration.

---

EDIT

I need to know how to read and decode above barcode. This barcodes were generated in legacy system and It would be nice if my app could OCR and understand them

On my barcode should be date 19.11.2010 15:43

Comment: Do you want to do this for the sake of determining what type it is, or is this part of an application that needs to read the barcode?

Comment: I need to know how to read and decode above barcode. 
This barcodes were generated in legacy system and It would be nice if my app could OCR and understand them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this [online bar code reader](http://www.onlinebarcodereader.com/), it an EAN_13 code for a product with the number 5252235562500.

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Product_Code) it's a product number for a discount coupon with manufacturer code 25223, family code 556 and coupon code 25.

If there is an expiration date encoded in the data, it's in some custom format encoded into the family code and coupon code. Otherwise you need a loopup table from the manufacturer to determine which coupon has which expiration date.

Comment: @Primoz: You can read the bar code as an EAN_13 code to get the digits that it contains, but the digits doesn't correspond to the date in any obvious format, so you need to know how the date is converted into a number to be able to do the reverse.

Answer (score 2):

How about, http://code.google.com/p/zxing/.

Answer (score 1):

There's an excellent barcode reading library named [Zebra crossing (zxing)](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/) available in Java with ports/wrappers to C#, C++, Ruby, etc.

This particular one is indeed EAN-13 code, which encodes 13 decimal digits [0-9] (2..3 country digits + 9..10 product digits + 1 checksum digit).

Answer (score 0):

The Wikipedia article referenced above seems to only refers to "coupon codes" only for UPC12 barcodes which are slightly different from EAN13 barcodes.

According to the offical GS1 site http://gepir.gs1.org/v31/xx/gtin.aspx?Lang=en-US this barcode is not defined as belonging to anyone (or country) so it is probably used internally by some organization for a custom application.

The GS1 site lot of information on barcode standards and formats.