# How to convert big int to date

Tags: mysql

How do I convert big int to date

Sample output:

```
name               due
release          | 1300150800000000
```

Description:

```
| name        | text       | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| due         | bigint(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
```

Comment: If you take it as microseconds since epoch: `perl -e ' print scalar localtime 1300150800'` you get March 15th, 2011

Comment: The date should be from year 2004-2011.

Comment: Check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261684/how-to-decode-some-number-into-timedate

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It seems it contains microseconds since `1970-Jan-01 00:00:00am GMT`.

That is after converting your value to seconds, it gives `1300150800`, which is equivalent to `2011-Mar-15 01:00:00am GMT`.

Therefore to convert it to a `datetime` you can use MySQL's [`FROM_UNIXTIME(unix_timestamp, format)`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime) after converting it to seconds (by dividing 1000000).

SQL:

```
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(due/1000000, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s") AS due_date 
FROM   MyTable;
```

Ref:

- [MySQL FROM_UNIXTIME()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime)
- [MySQL DATE_FORMAT()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)

Comment: @efox, It seems you're new to StackOverflow. Please accept if you got the answer.

Comment: It appears FROM_UNIXTIME() would introduce the [Y2K38 problem](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2012620/673991).  Wonder if there's an alternative that doesn't.  Otherwise (calculator tapping sounds) BIGINT seems good to year 9999 even counting microseconds.

Answer (score 0):

**select CAST( from_unixtime(end_time/1000) as DATE)  from myTable ;**

Output: 2015-03-01