# Reverse engineering date into some encoded number

Tags: reverse-engineering, decode, encode

I have one more question related to this thread. [How to decode some number into timeDate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261684/how-to-decode-some-number-into-timedate)

How can I generate this number for a given date ? Problem is sixth column for which I do not know how to get It.

Best regards, Primoz.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far I have tested it, the last two digits can be random. So this anwers my question.