# Reverse EAN-13 barcoding

Tags: reverse-engineering, barcode

This one is pretty much related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261684/how-to-decode-some-number-into-timedate) question.
I've got the following dates/times on barcodes, which correspond to some numbers.

**EDIT:** OK, I've got some additional examples. I followed the conversion method (second answer) from the related question and the results are not so encouraging :). The "converted into days" results are increasing, but unfortunately the calculated "zero" date is too :(

```
date on the barcode => scanned => part of the scan => converted into days => "zero" date
```

`24-02-16 09:33 => 2220447380512 => 2044738051 => 23665.94966435 => 10-05-51 10:45
 23-02-16 13:54 => 2220446806617 => 2044680661 => 23665.28542824 => 10-05-51 07:02
 23-02-16 09:15 => 2220446513713 => 2044651371 => 23664.94642361 => 10-05-51 10:32
 22-02-16 09:31 => 2220445725513 => 2044572551 => 23664.03415509 => 10-05-51 08:41
 19-02-16 09:18 => 2220444756617 => 2044475661 => 23662.91274306 => 08-05-51 11:23
 18-02-16 15:30 => 2220444237116 => 2044423711 => 23662.31146991 => 08-05-51 08:01
 18-02-16 15:07 => 2220444213912 => 2044421391 => 23662.28461806 => 08-05-51 08:17
 18-02-16 09:15 => 2220443823419 => 2044382341 => 23661.83265046 => 08-05-51 13:15
 17-02-16 17:15 => 2220442622716 => 2044347011 => 23661.42373843 => 08-05-51 07:04
 16-02-16 17:23 => 2220443470118 => 2044262271 => 23660.44295139 => 08-05-51 06:45
 11-02-16 14:20 => 2220439654119 => 2043965411 => 23657.00707176 => 06-05-51 14:09
 09-02-16 15:12 => 2220437896412 => 2043789641 => 23654.97269676 => 06-05-51 15:51`

Anyone?

Comment: What about [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4302658/180100) there's some decode code into it

Comment: Usually EAN-13 barcode numbers are issued by GS1 and worldwide unique. The exception are those numbers starting with 2, which can be used locally within a store or chain of stores. And the last digit is a checksum that is calculated from the other 12 digits. So if there is a date encoded in these numbers, you have to remove the last digit and probably the first or up to four digits at the beginning as well.

Comment: BTW: Are you sure you have copied the numbers correctly? They are in descending order except 2220442622716. That's very surprising.

Comment: It's my bad. I just fixed the order.